# Using Conditional Optimizations in Training Algorithm of Linear Support Vector Classifier

Tags: svm

I am trying to come up with an easier algorithm than usual nonlinear optimization algorithms for linear support vector classifier.

My idea is

1. Once classifier is determined, it's easy to decide support vectors (data misclassified + data near the discriminant plane)
2. Provided that support vectors are fixed, it's straightforward to compute linear classifier based only on those support vectors.

So my algorithm to compute Linear Support Vector Classifier is repeating following steps until convergence.

1. Based on given support vectors, train a linear classifier
2. With linear classifier computed in #1, find new support vectors.

Due to the fact this is a pretty obvious idea, I think somebody must've done something like this already. I am interested in how to prove that algorithm actually lead to convergence. Does anybody have any reference or clue?

Comment: I have two questions regarding your training algorithm. 1. How would you get initial parameters of your hyperplane (normal vector and intercept)? 2. When you determined new set of support vectors, how would you calculate the normal vector of the new hyperplane?

Comment: @Leo 1. I think OP can just use all data to get a classifier which would lead to LDA. 2. OP can just recompute LDA with those vectors.  Paul, Is this right? I think it's a simple and interesting idea.

Comment: @david Yes, that's pretty much what I have in my mind.

Comment: @david, I guess LDA is linear discriminant analysis, and what do you mean by OP?

Comment: @Leo OP = original poster